# WS2813 LED strip without controller

Tags: led, led-strip

I bought recently the LED strip WS2813 ( http://www.normandled.com/upload/201605/WS2813%20LED%20Datasheet.pdf ).

I use a DC 5V 20A power supply.

I soldered the V+ output to the +5V entry of the LED strip, and the ground to the ground. I did not connect anything yet to the DI/BI.

I measured voltage between V+ and V- and it's correct (5V).
However, the LED strip do not light up.

The question is: Do I need to send the signal to the DI/BI to expect something, or should it shine some light already ?

I have read that some model DO light without the controller, but I did not find anything on this specific model.

I have a raspberry pi that I will connect, with Hyperion to control the LED, but I would have expected the LED to already have done something by now.

Comment: A link to aliexpress is pretty useless, more so if in French. Find a datasheet from the manufacturer of the product.

Comment: My bad, changed it for the datasheet, sorry.

Comment: You purchased individually addressable, controlled LEDs.  If you want something that lights up with just power, you bought the wrong product - buy a simple string of non-addressable LEDs.  You can, however, likely make these light (especially in a fixed or simple pattern) with just about any tiny inexpensive microcontroller like an ATtiny, MSP430, STM8, PIC, etc... this is actually a rather bad fit for a Raspberry Pi, both because it's an awkward interface and because a pi brings a lot of additional requirements.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you need to provide a signal to the WS2813 chip to activate any colors.

The data should be input on the DI pin, it is almost compatible to the WS2812B, for which there exist many resources and microcontroller libraries. You only have to increase the reset duration to >280us.

[image: WS2813 application circuit]

If you have only one string, you should connect the BI pin to ground (V-), if you have multiple strings chained, connect the DI (input) to the DO (output) and the BI (backup input) to the BO (backup output) of the previous string and for the first string the BI to ground. The backup connections allow for one LED in the string to fail without the rest of the string going dark.